# 3 verbs in one sentence - correct order

Tags: verb, word-order, verbal-complex

> Es habe eine Zeit gedauert, bis sie selbst ihr Glück **habe** fassen
>   können.

Why is this not

> Es habe eine Zeit gedauert, bis sie selbst ihr Glück fassen können
>   **habe**.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You encountered a tricky word order rule which comes into effect for the *Perfekt* of modal expressions. The affinity of the **Ersatzinfinitiv** to the end of the clause is even higher than that of the conjugated verb in verb-last setting, and it infects all the infinitives in the row with its love for the end of the clause.

> Sie hat es gekonnt.
>
> …, obwohl sie es gekonnt hat.

Both sentences feature *können* as a full verb. Now as a modal verb, the *Ersatzinfinitiv* is used:

> Sie hat es sehen können.
>
> …, obwohl sie es hat sehen können.

Here, the finite verb *hat* is placed in front of the infinitive row. That word order rule also applies to longer infinitive rows:

> Sie hätte es kommen sehen müssen.
>
> …, obwohl sie es hätte kommen sehen müssen.

Tricky: In those dialects that don't use the *Ersatzinfinitiv* (mostly Bavarian and Austrian German) you may encounter both word orders:

> …, obwohl sie es hat sehen gekonnt.
>
> …, obwohl sie es sehen gekonnt hat.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation! It still feels and sounds weird to me. I suppose it’s a matter of getting used to it.

Comment: German is a melange of assorted wacky exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

The 3 verbs are in the correct order:

the Hilfsverb (haben) **conjugated to build the tense**

the full verb (fassen) infinitiv

the modalverb (können) Infinitiv