# Word order of pluperfect subjunctive

Tags: word-order, subjunctive, pluperfect

Consider this sentence:

> Dies ist für meinen Partner, ohne dessen Hilfe ich dieses Buch nie ***hätte** schreiben können*.
> <sub>(Source: Practising Grammar Workbook, p. 197)</sub>

Why is the word order of this pluperfect subjunctive "***hätte** schreiben können*" and not "*schreiben können **hätte***"?

Is this an exception to the rule that the active part of the verb should go to the end in secondary sentences? If so, why? And how is this construction called in German?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [3 verbs in one sentence - correct order](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/49676/3-verbs-in-one-sentence-correct-order)

Comment: Yes, thanks RHa.

Comment: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Grammatik#Reihenfolge_der_Verben

Answer (score 0):

I was always taught **T.I.M.**: Tense - infinitive - modal. Whenever you have this constellation of three verbs jostling for position at the end of the sentence,  where one is a modal (sollen/können etc.), the one that denotes the tense comes first, and the modal goes last.
Why this should be is beyond me, and what it is called I don't know. But this is how it works.